# python - explicit waits in page object model

Tags: python, selenium

How to use Page object pattern with explicit waits. This is my code for the testcases in a file called `test_page.py`:

```
class TestPages(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('http://abcd.com')

    def test_login_button(self):
        MainPage(self.driver).wait_for_button()
        # do some more actions 

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

This is where pages are defined in `page.py`:

```
class Page(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def find_element(self, *locator):
        return self.driver.find_element(*locator)

    def get_title(self):
        return self.driver.title

    def wait_for_element(self, *locator):
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 25).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((*locator)))


class MainPage(Page):

    def wait_for_button(self):
        return self.wait_for_element(*MainPageLocators.login_here)
```

And here in locators.py are the locators stored:

```
class MainPageLocators(object):
    logo = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.form > a > img')
    login_here = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn')
```

I am getting this error :

```
in wait_for_element
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(*locator))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So I added parenthesis around the `(*locator)` like this way:

Now this above code is giving me syntax error. What should I do , I am new to python.

Comment: I have deduced that if I remove '*' in:  self.wait_for_element(*MainPageLocators.login_here). It works just fine. But how I dont know